# No se actualiza el menu desplegable en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy intentando realizar un menú desplegable en el que al introducir un texto en el espacio de entrada de la parte inferior, aparezca ese elemento en el menú desplegable, en el código que anexo se puede ver que en la consola si se añade el elemento a la lista, pero no se porque no aparece en el espacio del menú. Seria de gran ayuda si me pudieran ayudar con esto y me dijesen ¿hay que actualizar el menú de alguna manera?.

Código:

```
from tkinter import *
ventana=Tk()
ventana.geometry("300x300+100+100")
ventana.title("Lista desplegable")
def nuevo_elemento():
    elemento=texto.get()
    print(opciones)
    print(elemento)
    opciones.append(elemento)
    print(opciones)

ventana.configure(bg="dark turquoise")
var=StringVar(ventana)
var.set('Tarea1')
opciones=['Tarea1']
lista=OptionMenu(ventana, var, *opciones)
texto=Entry(ventana)
color=Label(ventana,textvariable=var)
l1=Label(ventana, text="Tarea: ")
boton_nuevatarea=Button(ventana,text="Nueva tarea",command=nuevo_elemento)
lista.place(relx=.1,rely=.1,relwidth=.6,relheight=.1)
l1.place(relx=.1,rely=.3,relwidth=.6,relheight=.1)
color.place(relx=.1,rely=.4,relwidth=.6,relheight=.1)
boton_nuevatarea.place(relx=.1,rely=.6,relwidth=.3,relheight=.1)
texto.place(relx=.1,rely=.8,relwidth=.6,relheight=.1)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No importa que cambios hagas a la lista de opciones opciones, el menú simplemente no se actualizará. Por que la lista es una cosa y el contenido del menú otra muy diferente. Cambiar el contenido de la lista no alterará al menu del mismo modo que agregar items al menu no alterará la lista.

Basandome en [esta pagina](https://www.plus2net.com/python/tkinter-OptionMenu-proj1.php) determiné como puedes agregar elementos al optionmenu.
El unico tema es que tendrás que actualizar a la vez la lista de opciones.

```
from tkinter import *

# Notese este import extra que hago.
# Esto es escencial para obtener de manera prolija la función tk._setit
import tkinter as tk

ventana=Tk()
ventana.geometry("300x300+100+100")
ventana.title("Lista desplegable")

def nuevo_elemento():
    elemento=texto.get()

    # Obtengo el objeto que representa al menú que aparece al hacer clic.
    # Posteriormente, guardo dicho objeto en la variable menu.
    menu = lista['menu']

    # Creo una función (las funciones son objetos) con el comando interno _setit cuyo proposito será darle al stringvar var el valor en la variable "elemento"
    # Esta función será la responsable de que al hacer clic al elemento, este se seleccione.
    # Vamos a guardar la función en la variable set_option
    set_option = tk._setit(var, elemento)

    # Añado el item. El nombre del item se lo paso a través del parametro label.
    # Gracias al parametro command enlaso la función guardada en set_option con el evento en el cual el usuario hace clic.
    menu.add_command(label=elemento, command=set_option)

    # A su vez actualizo la lista
    opciones.append(elemento)

    


ventana.configure(bg="dark turquoise")
var=StringVar(ventana)
var.set('Tarea1')
opciones=['Tarea1']
lista=OptionMenu(ventana, var, *opciones)
texto=Entry(ventana)
color=Label(ventana,textvariable=var)
l1=Label(ventana, text="Tarea: ")
boton_nuevatarea=Button(ventana,text="Nueva tarea",command=nuevo_elemento)
lista.place(relx=.1,rely=.1,relwidth=.6,relheight=.1)
l1.place(relx=.1,rely=.3,relwidth=.6,relheight=.1)
color.place(relx=.1,rely=.4,relwidth=.6,relheight=.1)
boton_nuevatarea.place(relx=.1,rely=.6,relwidth=.3,relheight=.1)
texto.place(relx=.1,rely=.8,relwidth=.6,relheight=.1)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Sin embargo, creo que hacer todo esto es de más existiendo el widget [ttk.Combobox](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/lista-desplegable-combobox-en-tkinter/) del modulo ttk.
Es decir, podrías lograr lo mismo usando menos código y sin tener que actualizar constantemente una lista.

```
from tkinter import *

# importo el modulo ttk
from tkinter import ttk

ventana=Tk()
ventana.geometry("300x300+100+100")
ventana.title("Lista desplegable")
def nuevo_elemento():
    elemento=texto.get()

    print(lista["values"])
    print(elemento)

    # Agregamos al final menú desplegable del combobox el ultimo elemento
    # lista["values"] devuelve una tupla con todos los elementos, por lo que debemos crear una nueva tupla que tenga al final el elemento a agregar
    # y poner de valores a esa nueva tupla
    lista["values"] += (elemento,)
    print(lista["values"])

ventana.configure(bg="dark turquoise")
var=StringVar(ventana)
var.set('Tarea1')
opciones=['Tarea1']

# Creo el combobox. El primer argumento es la ventana donde lo creamos.
# Textvariable es a que variable de control (en este caso StringVar) está asociado el contenido del combobox
# Con el parametro values agregamos algunos valores iniciales al combobox
# Pasandole state="readonly" hacemos que el usuario no pueda modificar el contenido del combobox pero si elegir una opción.
lista=ttk.Combobox(ventana, textvariable=var, values=opciones, state="readonly")

texto=Entry(ventana)
color=Label(ventana,textvariable=var)
l1=Label(ventana, text="Tarea: ")
boton_nuevatarea=Button(ventana,text="Nueva tarea",command=nuevo_elemento)
lista.place(relx=.1,rely=.1,relwidth=.6,relheight=.1)
l1.place(relx=.1,rely=.3,relwidth=.6,relheight=.1)
color.place(relx=.1,rely=.4,relwidth=.6,relheight=.1)
boton_nuevatarea.place(relx=.1,rely=.6,relwidth=.3,relheight=.1)
texto.place(relx=.1,rely=.8,relwidth=.6,relheight=.1)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Como habrás notado, el Combobox es mucho mejor a la hora de escribir el código. Y aun mejor, no necesitas crear una lista de opciones por que ya puedes acceder al contenido actual del combobox con `tucombobox["values"]`.

Pregunta curiosa: Piensas cambiar el optionmenu por un combobox o usar mi primera solución?

Comment: Intente utilizar la primera opcion, sin embargo la segunda opcion me fue mejor para poder seguir trabajando sobre este codigo, fue de gran ayuda entender a detalle como trabaja el combobox. gracias :)

Comment: Tengo una pregunta Hay alguna manera de que este archivo quede permanentemente en la lista, es decir, que al cerrar la ventana y volver a ejecutarla ya aparezca en el combobox? Lo he intentado y no he visto la manera

Comment: @fernandomosquera a que te refieres? A que una vez que agregas items al combobox y cierras la ventana, puedas volver a ejecutar el programa y aparezcan todos los items que agregaste antes?

Comment: Exactamente, estaba pensando en que quizas si pudiese guardar los elementos en un archivo txt, y que al ejecutar el programa los mostrara en el combobox podria ser una opcion, pero no estoy seguro de como hacerlo o si es posible

Comment: @fernandomosquera Si es posible! Simplemente crea con Python un txt donde cada línea sea un valor del combobox. Por ejemplo si tu combobox tiene de valores ("1", "2", "3") crea un txt que sea linea1: 1, linea2: 2, linea3: 3. Luego, abre el archivo en modo lectura y usa `combo["values"] = archivo.read().splitlines()`. Información sobre como abrir un txt en esta pagina: https://www.programaenpython.com/fundamentos/leer-y-escribir-ficheros-de-texto/

Comment: Intenta hacerlo por tu cuenta, si te surge una duda, escribe una pregunta en este sitio, seguramente yo o alguien más decida contestarte con una respuesta más detallada c: Recuerda que si quieres que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida es buena idea agregar el código que lograste hacer hasta ese entonces. Suerte!

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias voy a indagar al respecto para desarrollarlo adecuadamente, cualquier duda la realizare aunque esperemos no sea necesario, nuevamente muchas gracias